# Change meta description

Tags: meta-tags

I created a website for my small company and I wanted to share it on social media site. Doing so, I noted I get the *Lorem Ipsum* dummy text as meta description.

> [image: screenshot]

How do I change that text?

Comment: Check if the Metatag module installed. if yes go to its configuration form page.

Comment: That was the first thing i have checked but didn't find any module for Metatag.

Comment: Isn't this the site slogan to be configured in site settings? That's no meta title.

Comment: I think @leymannx is right.

Comment: @kiamlaluno – I'm not 100% sure. I first thought the screenshot is showing OP's site. But now I think the screenshot is showing the moment when you paste an URL into Facebook and Facebook pulls the meta information from the URL to preview. Then the question maybe really is about meta tags. But still too broad.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your effort and suggestion, @leymannx my site slogan is empty, because i have included the slogan into the logo. The problem is when i paste the link in Facebook i get the descriptions that shows in the screenshot. I have searched the files of the theme but with no success, I have installed Drupal 8.

Comment: @EnzoMuho – Wow try googling for "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing" and you will find looots of Facebook entries. Seems Facebook is putting this text in there when you didn't configure a meta description on your own. So simply follow the first comment, install the Metatag module and configure site and/or node meta descriptions.